# Groupby in not working when aggregation funtion is used in sql Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

the following SQL query is not grouping all the same items, i had attached an image for it making clear to all . [![enter image description here][1]][1]

in the image the according to currency of each branch should be groupby but it is not grouping with same currency.

```
SELECT BR.BranchName BranchName,
        PDS.ProductName Currency, 
        SUM( FCBSD.Quantity) Quantity,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,3),
        (FCBSD.Quantity*FCBSD.DealingRate))) LocalCurrency
        ,case when (FCBSD.IsBuy=0) then 'Sell' else 'Buy'end [Type],
        SUM(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), FCBSD.Quantity*FCBSD.DealingRate))) OVER (PARTITION BY BR.BranchID)  [TOAL] 
FROM ALX_FCBuySell FCSB
    LEFT JOIN ALX_FCBuySellDetails  FCBSD ON FCSB.FCBuySellID= FCBSD.FCBuySellID
    LEFT JOIN ALX_Branches BR ON FCSB.BranchID= BR.BranchID                 
    LEFT JOIN ALX_Products PDS ON FCBSD.ProductID=PDS.ProductID
GROUP BY BR.BranchName, PDS.ProductName,BR.BranchID,FCBSD.Quantity,FCBSD.IsBuy
ORDER BY BR.BranchName
```

it is the Exact out i need each currency should be groupby under type and each branch
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What is the expected output then?

Comment: out put is the sum in of the each currecny in each branch

Comment: ie, summ of all UAE Dirhams in Exibition branch ,here it shows 2 but i need only one UAE dirhams and the quantity is 1500 and local currency as 565.625

Comment: You claimed that it did not work, but you did not provide the expected output. How do we know?

Comment: What is the out put if you add these `BR.BranchID,FCBSD.Quantity,FCBSD.IsBuy` to the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: i will atach the exact out put for a sample reference

Comment: Try to replace `FCBSD.IsBuy` to your whole `case` statement in your group by

Comment: @too many Alex. how it is the condition for the statement.. for that only u make down vote for me. i dont know it is a mistake .

Comment: @DonaSusanIssac I don't remember I have down vote for this question, at least the system state that I don't have down vote for this question at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT BR.BranchName BranchName,
        PDS.ProductName Currency, 
        SUM( FCBSD.Quantity) Quantity,
        FCBSD.DealingRate Rate,
        SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,3), (FCBSD.Quantity*FCBSD.DealingRate))) LocalCurrency,
        case when (FCBSD.IsBuy=0) then 'Sell' else 'Buy'end [Type],
        SUM(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), FCBSD.Quantity*FCBSD.DealingRate))) OVER (PARTITION BY BR.BranchID)  [TOAL] 
 FROM ALX_FCBuySell FCSB
        LEFT JOIN ALX_FCBuySellDetails  FCBSD ON FCSB.FCBuySellID= FCBSD.FCBuySellID
        LEFT JOIN ALX_Branches BR ON FCSB.BranchID= BR.BranchID                 
        LEFT JOIN ALX_Products PDS ON FCBSD.ProductID=PDS.ProductID
        LEFT JOIN ALX_Customers CUS ON FCSB.CustomerID =CUS.CustomerID 
    GROUP BY BR.BranchID, BR.BranchName, FCBSD.ProductID ,PDS.ProductName,FCBSD.DealingRate,
            BR.BranchID,FCBSD.IsBuy
    ORDER BY BR.BranchName
```

In your code you must remove the FCBSD.Quantity from the group by. so you should get all the currencies in groupby form according to the Type and branches try this and post your comments